null keyword on class declaration
Out of curiosity, I was looking through the files of a simple Android application developed for controlling a machine (I didn't develop it, which isn't relevant to the question, I suppose). I'm trying to get the app running on my laptop to see how it works. In the code, I found many appearances of the following:
class null implements AdapterViewICS.OnItemClickListener 
{

  //... some other stuff

}

I have no experience with Java code at all, but when using Android Studio to view these files the null keyword is marked as an error: java: <identifier> expected, which seems reasonable although I don't understand how this happened (I didn't change the code and the app works on my phone). My hypothesis is that most of these classes aren't used in the actual application and that's why these errors never caused trouble (if they are even errors at all), but they are now preventing me from running on my computer and I'd like to fix that.
Could anyone with Java experience tell me if this is correct, or explain why this could have happened (maybe some quirk in the decompiling?)
I've tried looking up class definition syntax for Java but I haven't found anything about null being used as an accesor, return type, or anything as such.
Also when changing null to Null the error disappears (as expected) and the class is marked with no usages. This confuses me because I'm unsure if the class wasn't ever used in the first place or doesn't appear now since I changed its identifier.

Did you find that code in the source code repository of the application or was it decompiled? If it was you decompiling it, it might be something an obfuscator added. Alternatively (again, with decompiling), it would be possible that the class was generated from Kotlin which allows using keywords as class names if you tell it to.

@dan1st Yes, I did decompile it using JD-GUI. If this was the case... Is there a way to set android studio to do the same?

To do what? @dan1st seems to have answered your question.

What I mean is: If this is the case (that keywords were in fact used as class names), what can I do to get the app running on my computer? Change all class names? Change some settings? Again, I'm absolutely new to Java and everything related.

This seems to be the product of an obfuscator (like ProGuard). An obfuscator works on the generated byte code and is therefore not bound by the rules of the original language. That means it can freely use Java keywords as class, method and field names. It can (and will) also replace class, method and field names by shorter names like a, b, .., z, aa, Aa etc. They are explicitly written to make decompiling and studying the source hard. There is no simple solution to reverse the effects of an obfuscator.


Also when changing null to Null the error disappears (as expected) and the class is marked with no usages.

Of course; java is, like most programming languages, case sensitive. a class named null and a class named Null as different as a class named Guns and a class named Grandmas.
Insofar that null was somehow used, changing that to Null would, obviously, mean nobody uses it - they'd be using null, not Null.

class null

That'd be a decompiler error... probably.
Java-the-language dictates that classes cannot have a keyword as a name, and null is a keyword. Hence, javac refuses to compile this.
However, java-the-virtual-machine doesn't actually care. Some JVM-targeted languages allow you to 'escape' a keyword, such as scala or kotlin with backticks where you really could write:
// Except in scala syntax of course
class `null` { ... }

But java-the-language isn't one of those. You cannot make javac produce the class file representing a class named null no matter how hard you try, but with other compilers, or some byte code hacking (modifying a .class file), you can, and java.exe would run it just fine.
it is likely the decompiler messed up. Decompilers are crappy and will likely always be, because professionals are effectively never in a situation where they need to decompile (just get the source), and no amount of awesomeness in a decompiler is going to restore comments for you, and comments are very useful.
However, an obfuscator might have gone for the hack of naming one class in every package null, because in class files only you can actually pull that off. I'd expect other keywords too if that is the case - classes named for, while, class, interface, and so on.

In Java - null is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a class name. The error you are seeing is because null is not a valid identifier. The code you're looking at may have been obfuscated or decompiled incorrectly.
Actually AdapterViewICS full name is: android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewICS, so its from android support library which is not of interest for you if you want to learn how some application works (its implementation can be easily found). If proguard didnt remove this class then its probably used in app so changing its name will cause some other part of application to not compile.
Support library allows to run your app on many different android versions. In this case AdapterViewICS is (probably) a specialized implementation for Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS) android - or just a name added when ICS came out - at around 2011.
AdapterView is used in implementation of GUI lists on android. If you want to learn how some application implements lists then look into:
AdapterView
Android RecyclerView Sample
